Updated compileSdkVersion to 34 in React Native project, but unable to connect to Metro server
I recently updated my React Native project's compileSdkVersion from 33 to 34 to comply with Google's new policy. After making this change, I am unable to connect to the Metro server. Here are the details of my android/app/build.gradle configuration:
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    ndkVersion = "25.0.8775105"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 34
    }
}



My project setup includes:

React version: 18.2.0
React Native version: 0.72.3

Steps I've taken so far:

Updated compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 34 in android/app/build.gradle.
Cleaned the project using ./gradlew clean.
Reinstalled node modules rm -rf node_modules && npm install or yarn install
Rebuilt the project with npx react-native run-android
Started the Metro server manually using npx react-native start
Despite these steps, the Metro server fails to connect when running the app. I have also verified that all my dependencies are up to date.


First update the android/build.gradle
 compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34

if your code work file then ok In my case my app crash after these changes so I reslved app crash my changes these
MainApplication.java
    // Add imports
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.IntentFilter;
   import android.os.Build;
   import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;


   // ...
   // Put this above  "public void onCreate()":
  @Override
  public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
  }
// ....

app/build.gradle
    dependencies {
     //  ...
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
    // ...
}


Does build tools and AGP remains the same?

I read you need to upgrade react-native to 0.74
